# Returning an anonymous type from lambda / code explanation

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection

This code comes from mr.Lukazoid member of stackoverflow. I would like to know how this works. It is a bit strange to me how you call a method like this. What is the role of `TResult`?

```
public static string[] Foo<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> func)
{
    return typeof(TResult).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToArray();
}

Foo((Person x) => new { x.LastName, x.DateOfBirth });
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `TResult` is the result type of the passed in expression, `func`. In your example, it would be the anonymous type containing members `LastName` and `DateOfBirth`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is trying to get a subset of property names from a class in a typed way.

There are several ways to do this, however the author has chosen a very sneaky way that takes advantage of [*generic inference*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) to save the cost of a delegate / expression invocation. This is why `func` is never called...

To achieve this, the author has relied on the fact that *generic type parameters* are *statically compiled* and can be *inferred* by the the parameters of the method.

The *generic parameters* in this case are `<T, TResult>`. `T` is *inferred* from `(Person x)` (the parameter side of the lamda), while `TResult` is *inferred* from `new { x.LastName, x.DateOfBirth }` (the body of the lambda).

Since *generics* are compile time language feature, the method can access the reflexive properties of `typeof(TResult)`... without ever needing to invoke / execute the *expression*.

This seems great, job done. However, the same could be done with a [`Func` delegate](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-func-delegate) at considerable less cost

```
public static string[] Foo2<T,TResult>(Func<T, TResult> _)
  => typeof(TResult).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToArray();
```

**Benchmarks**

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Expression | 2,852.9 ns | 47.68 ns | 44.60 ns |
| Func | 122.7 ns | 2.47 ns | 2.31 ns |

But wait, there's more... Both of these methods are ***extremely*** suspect. We are in essence dealing with compile time constructs and using reflection every time the definitions are needed, which on a hot path would cause considerable and unnecessary overhead. Ideally, you would just use an array of `nameof()` and store it for later use (or not)

```
new[]{nameof(Person.DateOfBirth),nameof(Person.LastName)}
```

Which would compile to this

```
 string[] array = new string[2];
 array[0] = "DateOfBirth";
 array[1] = "LastName";
```

Even with the overhead of allocation it is factors more efficient than either of the methods above.

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Expression | 2,939.355 ns | 58.0773 ns | 88.6902 ns |
| Func | 123.211 ns | 2.5011 ns | 4.1094 ns |
| NameOf | 9.606 ns | 0.2555 ns | 0.2734 ns |

Comment: Or find a way to cache the names statically, eg; `public class Foo3<T>{ static string[] Names = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(pi => pi.Name).ToArray(); }`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Its a great point. I was going to go down a similar path with the conclusion that any caching would be better than just use reflection willy-nilly, However, i made the extreme point of `nameof` for the sake of brevity and extra flavour :).

Answer (score 0):

`Func<T, TResult>` means, a function that is declared like this:

`TResult functionName(T parameter)`.

In other words, `TResult` is the type of the value returned by the function. Preceding types (`T` in this case) are the types of the parameters passed to the function.

In this code, `Foo((Person x) => new { x.LastName, x.DateOfBirth });`, the method `Foo` is being passed an anonymous method with signature `Func<Person, AnonymousTypeContainingNameAndBirth>`

In other words, `TResult` is `AnonymousTypeContainingNameAndBirth`.

> Since the `Foo` method is expecting an `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`, that anonymous method is actually converted to an expression before being passed to Foo, but that's a story for another discussion.

The code you provided returns `string[] { "LastName", "DateOfBirth" }`.